# What locales are supported in the Intl API in Node.js by default?

Tags: node.js

The Node docs [say](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html#intl_internationalization_support) you have to build your own `node` binary configured with the flag `--with-intl=full-icu` if you need to support all languages. (Aside: there's an [open feature request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19214) to build Node like this by default.)

What locales are included by in Node's standard builds today? I can't find a simple list anywhere.